# How to get stack trace during runtime android

Tags: android, trace

My app is not behaving as I expect. After the device is going to sleep (black screen) and is turned on, the device shows the screen of my app, but then a moment later part of the screen disappears - the tabbed viewpager which is below the toolbar.

I put a break point at the last point where my app is doing anything and the screen is still fine, so it is something the system is doing but I do not know what.

Is there a way to turn on a stack trace so that very method the system is using from that point on is logged and maybe that will allow me to find out why the tabbed viewpager disappears?

I should mention that the app is still functioning properly and I am able to open the navigation drawer from the toolbar and use all it's functions but I cannot see anymore the tabbed viewpager, until I recreate it.

Comment: I don't suppose it throws an exception? If so you could try an exception breakpoint

Comment: No exceptions. I want a trace with no exceptions, to know what is the system doing

Comment: Where did you set break point? e.g. Activity.onCreate(), Fragment.onCreateView(), at the initialization code of ViewPager or TabLayout

Answer (score 2):

Android Studio includes a debugger that allows you to debug apps running on the Android Emulator or a connected Android device. With the Android Studio debugger, you can:

Select a device to debug your app on.
Set breakpoints in your code.
Examine variables and evaluate expressions at runtime.

For more info visit https://developer.android.com/studio/debug/index.html

Comment: Didn't he state he already posted a breakpoint, so I assume he's already using Android Studio

Comment: Anyway, using Android Studio debugger is the best method for debugging this problem.

Answer (score 2):

If you are able to get back the logs properly, most probably the issue may be resolved.  As others mentioned, logcat is a good option.

A refined solution can be an efficient logger system, which will capture all logs. You can write these to a local file for your future reference.

[JakeWharton's Hugo](https://github.com/JakeWharton/hugo) is such an awesome library where you need only little modifications using annotations `@DebugLog` . This will capture your application logs and print in logcat.

Your `bundle.gradle (Module:app)` should be modified as follows

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'
apply plugin: 'hugo'
android {
    compileSdkVersion 24
    buildToolsVersion "23.0.3"
    ....... Other configurations
```

In the `bundle.gradle (Project)` these should be present

```
buildscript {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:2.1.2'
        classpath 'com.jakewharton.hugo:hugo-plugin:1.2.1'
    }
}
```

In order to make `hugo` track your application logs  `@DebugLog`  needs to be added . For example , in your class methods. You can find this in [hugo sample](https://github.com/JakeWharton/hugo/tree/master/hugo-example)

Now inorder to get logs back, do the following .

> The following code does not have to do anything with hugo library, it
>   will just capture logs from logcat.

Inside and AsyncTask do the following and write the content to a file and verify those.

```
        @Override
        protected String doInBackground(Void... voids) {
            String responseString = null;

                try {

                    Process process = Runtime.getRuntime().exec("logcat -b main -d");
                    BufferedReader bufferedReader = new BufferedReader(
                            new InputStreamReader(process.getInputStream()));
                    String line;
                    StringBuilder log=new StringBuilder();
                    while ((line = bufferedReader.readLine()) != null) {

                            log.append(line);
                            log.append('\n');
                            log.append("-----------");
                    }
                    responseString = log.toString();

                } catch (Exception e) {
                }
            return responseString;
        }
```

It may look complicated, but believe me, its way good enough than other libraries and simplifies developers work.

You can also try with `Runtime.getRuntime().exec("logcat -d");`

Good Luck , Try it out. !!

Answer (score 1):

You can log a stack trace at any point without throwing anything or otherwise interrupting the program.

```
Log.d("DERP", "check out my stack trace", new RuntimeException());
```

Comment: This will not do since the problem is due to Android code doing something and not my code. Thus I can not add that statement to my code. 

What I want is an option that I can activate and from that moment on, until I deactivate it, each method being executed is listed.

Answer (score -1):

2 things are possible. First one is you are doing something in onResume (some network hit and/or ui update). Second one is activity recreate. So you can test you app with do not keep activity option on. It will help you to identify exact problem.